# SQL Table- Combine Rows Based on Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table like

```
DateCol       TaskID     EventName
2017-09-25    10         A
2017-07-26    10         B
2017-07-27    10         A
2017-09-14    10         A
2017-07-25    10         B
2017-09-25    10         C
2017-09-28    11         A
2017-11-01    11         D
2017-11-01    11         C
```

.....many thousands of rows

What I'd like is an output that, for each TaskID, if events A and C (not any other combination) occurred on the same day (from DateCol), EventName column is "A+C". So in this case it would show

```
DateCol       TaskID     EventName
2017-09-25    10         A+C
2017-07-26    10         B
2017-07-27    10         A
2017-09-14    10         A
2017-07-25    10         B
2017-09-28    11         A
2017-11-01    11         D
2017-11-01    11         C
```

You can see that row

```
2017-09-25    10         A
```

and

```
2017-09-25    10         C
```

are now one row,

```
2017-09-25    10         A+C
```

but nothing else is changed.

What kind of SQL statement would I have to do to make such an adjustment?

Comment: SQL alone cannot do this task but you can do this using a program.

Comment: @HoneyYadav SQL alone can certainly do this task...

Comment: @TylerRoper If it is possible then I would also like to know answer.

Comment: @HoneyYadav I'm quite confident this can be done in SQL. I just can't figure out the right kinds of rownum/partitions, group bys or case statements necessary to do so.

Comment: @John Is there the possibility for repeated events on the same date? For example, two A's and two C's on the same day? If so, what's the desired output?

Comment: @HoneyYadav I believe you have a few options :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assumption : only combine 2 different EventName into 1.

a bit crude, but it should work.

```
; with
cte as
(
    select  t.DateCol, t.TaskID, 
        t.EventName,
        new_EventName   = 
            case when   t.EventName in ('A')        
                 and    max(t.EventName) over (partition by t.DateCol, t.TaskID)    = 'C'
                 then   'A+C'
                 when   t.EventName in ('C')
                 and    min(t.EventName) over (partition by t.DateCol, t.TaskID)    = 'A'
                 then   'A+C'
                 else   NULL
                 end
    from    yourtable t
)
select  distinct DateCol, TaskID, EventName = coalesce(new_EventName, EventName)
from    cte
```

if there are other scenario that this does not work, please post the sample data with the expected result

Comment: This seems to work great, thanks Squirrel. I've tested with a couple scenarios and will circle back if I find any scenarios I missed that this doesn't work for.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the most efficient way to do this would be a self-`JOIN`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    mt1.DateCol, 
    mt1.TaskId,
    (CASE 
        WHEN mt2.EventName IS NULL THEN mt1.EventName 
        ELSE 'A+C' 
    END) as EventName
FROM 
    MyTable mt1
LEFT JOIN MyTable mt2 ON 
    mt1.DateCol = mt2.DateCol 
    AND ((mt1.EventName = 'A' AND mt2.EventName = 'C') OR (mt1.EventName = 'C' AND mt2.EventName = 'A'))
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dc3f1/43)

Answer (score 0):

So first you need a primary key/ unique column for all row.Then we find all the row who have A and C on the same date. We can use selfjoin for this. Also I assume the `TaskId` between `EventName` A and C is always the same.

For example if the Table name is `TableX` and primary key column is `PrimaryX`

```
Select A.DateCol, A.TaskID, 'A+C' AS EventName FROM TableX A INNER JOIN TableX B 
ON A.DateCol = B.DateCol AND (EventName ='A' OR EventName ='C')
```

Then we union with the normal but the normal query do not take the same data from our previous query. For this we can use not in on column `PrimaryX`

```
Select DateCol, TaskID, 'A+C' AS EventName FROM TableX A WHERE PrimaryX not in 
(Select A.PrimaryX  AS EventName FROM TableX A INNER JOIN TableX B 
ON A.DateCol = B.DateCol AND (EventName ='A' OR EventName ='C')) AND PrimaryX not in 
(Select B.PrimaryX  AS EventName FROM TableX A INNER JOIN TableX B 
ON A.DateCol = B.DateCol AND (EventName ='A' OR EventName ='C'))
UNION
Select A.DateCol, A.TaskID, 'A+C' AS EventName FROM TableX A INNER JOIN TableX B 
ON A.DateCol = B.DateCol AND (EventName ='A' OR EventName ='C')
```