# Merge rows and concatenate based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, concatenation

****Raw Data****

| Orders | Service | ID | Date | State | Name | Results |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | Vitals | 12345 | 10/2/2019 | Alabama | Systole | 115 |
| 39 | Vitals | 12345 | 10/2/2019 | Alabama | BMI | 27.5 |
| 62 | Vitals | 12345 | 10/2/2019 | Alabama | Diastole | 64 |
| 519 | Vitals | 12345 | 10/2/2019 | Alabama | Diastole | 70 |
| 114 | Vitals | 12345 | 11/5/2019 | Alabama | Systole | 111 |
| 442 | Vitals | 12345 | 11/5/2019 | Alabama | BMI | 28 |
| 10 | Vitals | 12345 | 12/19/2019 | Alabama | BMI | 29 |
| 89 | Vitals | 12345 | 12/19/2019 | Alabama | Systole | 100 |
| 90 | Vitals | 12345 | 12/19/2019 | Alabama | Diastole | 62 |
| 529 | Vitals | 12345 | 12/19/2019 | Alabama | Diastole | 90 |
| 417 | Vitals | 12345 | 12/19/2019 | Alabama | Systole | 99 |
| 77 | Vitals | 12345 | 4/7/2020 | Alabama | Systole | 110 |
| 78 | Vitals | 12345 | 4/7/2020 | Alabama | Diastole | NULL |
| 343 | Vitals | 12345 | 4/7/2020 | Alabama | BMI | 23 |
| 120 | Vitals | 12345 | 4/7/2020 | Alabama | Diastole | NULL |
| 321 | Vitals | 12345 | 4/7/2020 | Alabama | Systole | 106 |
| 39 | Vitals | 12345 | 9/29/2020 | Alabama | Diastole | 82 |
| 97 | Vitals | 12345 | 9/29/2020 | Alabama | Systole | 120 |
| 815 | Vitals | 12345 | 9/29/2020 | Alabama | BMI | 22 |
| 19 | Vitals | 12345 | 2/2/2021 | Alabama | Systole | 108 |
| 20 | Vitals | 12345 | 2/2/2021 | Alabama | Diastole | 59 |
| 983 | Vitals | 12345 | 2/2/2021 | Alabama | BMI | 24 |
| 984 | Vitals | 12345 | 2/2/2021 | Alabama | Systole | 133 |
| 210 | Vitals | 12345 | 2/2/2021 | Alabama | Diastole | 68 |

**Outcome Desired**

| Service | ID | Date | State | Name | Results |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Vitals | 12345 | 10/2/2019 | Alabama | Blood Pressure | 115/70 |
| Vitals | 12345 | 10/2/2019 | Alabama | BMI | 27.5 |
| Vitals | 12345 | 11/5/2019 | Alabama | Systole | 111 |
| Vitals | 12345 | 11/5/2019 | Alabama | BMI | 28 |
| Vitals | 12345 | 12/19/2019 | Alabama | BMI | 29 |
| Vitals | 12345 | 12/19/2019 | Alabama | Blood Pressure | 100/90 |
| Vitals | 12345 | 4/7/2020 | Alabama | Systole | 110 |
| Vitals | 12345 | 4/7/2020 | Alabama | Diastole | NULL |
| Vitals | 12345 | 4/7/2020 | Alabama | BMI | 23 |
| Vitals | 12345 | 4/7/2020 | Alabama | Diastole | NULL |
| Vitals | 12345 | 4/7/2020 | Alabama | Systole | 106 |
| Vitals | 12345 | 9/29/2020 | Alabama | BMI | 22 |
| Vitals | 12345 | 9/29/2020 | Alabama | Blood Pressure | 120/82 |
| Vitals | 12345 | 2/2/2021 | Alabama | BMI | 24 |
| Vitals | 12345 | 2/2/2021 | Alabama | Blood Pressure | 133/68 |

*Disclaimer - this is just one subset of data belonging to the ID 12345, there are thousands more.*

I would like to have a query that returns the outcome desired picture using sql server where :

1. Based on ID, Date, and State - merge the MAX of systole and diastole in the format of "systole"/"diastole" in the Results column
2. The merged is categorized as blood pressure in the name column
3. There are times when a diastole or systole is missing or null. If that's the case, leave it. (In outcome desired picture - see date 11/5/2019 and 4/7/2020 for clarification

I've used [this link as a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413921/sql-table-combine-rows-based-on-conditions) to help but am coming up short. Not sure how to include the conditions stated above with the results.

```
With test as
    
(
select  service,ID, Date, state, Name, results, case when  name = 'Systole' or t.BiometricName= 'Diastole'then   'Blood Pressure' else Name end [New_Name] 
from    mytable t ) 

SELECT DIStiNCT service,    ID,     Date,   state,  Name,   results,            new_name
FROM test
```

Sorry, not very good with this markdown (I'll try to edit this) and I hope I am not making this too bloated.

Using SQL server 2014 - 12.0.5223.6

Thanks in advance

Comment: Images if data doesn't help us help you. Take the time to post sample data in a **consumable** format; preferable DDL and DML statements. As for the problem, what have *you* tried to solve the problem so far? Why didn't it work?

Comment: @Larnu Hey there. Thanks for the response and etiquette info - I have posted a consumable format. I'm a sporadic user in sql and honestly not quite sure where to start. I used the "With" function to get to a subset of data that I want but it's nothing worth mentioning.

Comment: What is you SQL server version?

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy Hey - in the about section in my SSMS shows that I'm using ver. 15.0.18369.0

Comment: That's the SSMS version.  Do `SELECT @@Version` in a query window to get the actual SQL Server version of the instance you're connected to.  What have you tried and what are you stuck on?  Show us your code so we can help you with it.

Comment: @squillman Hey - I get SSMS 2014 - 12.0.5223.6. Trying to relate to this previous question I have found, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413921/sql-table-combine-rows-based-on-conditions) _italic_ **bold** `code`.

Comment: Ok, but again that's not SSMS, that's SQL Server (just so you're aware in the future when someone asks you for the version).  SSMS is the _client_ you're using to connect to a _MS SQL Server instance_.  Help | About gives you the SSMS version, SELECT @@Version gives you the SQL Server version.  They're different products and it makes a big difference which one you're looking at.  So you're using SSMS 15.0 (which is reaally v18.9.2 of the whole overall product) and SQL Server 2014.

Comment: @squillman thanks for the info and apologize for the lack of experience with it. A typo earlier it is SQL server 2014 - 12.0.5223.6.

Comment: @Michael Oh no worries!  Not trying to sound gruff, just helping out making you aware.

Comment: @squillman Sure thing. I'm trying to be as responsive as I can and try to follow other peoples' question/post etiquette like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413921/sql-table-combine-rows-based-on-conditions) which I used for reference and help to my question.

Comment: Great, can you edit your question and add it so it's easier to see?

Comment: @squillman this is what I have so far 

With test as

(
    select  service,
   ID,
   Date,
   state,
   Name,
   results,
   case when  name = 'Systole' or t.BiometricName= 'Diastole'
                 then   'Blood Pressure'
     else Name
   end [New_Name]
from    mytable
)

SELECT DISTINCT service,
   ID,
   Date,
   state,
   Name,
   results,
   new_name
   
FROM test


I'm unable to get the values correct based on my conditions when the results or null or missing etc...

Comment: @squillman I have modified the question to include things from the comment section. Hopefully this will suffice. If not, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of clever aggregation should do the trick.

```sql
select
  service,
  ID,
  Date,
  state,
  case when min(name) = 'Diastole' and max(name) = 'Systole' then 'Blood Pressure' else min(Name) end AS [New_Name],
  case when min(name) = 'Diastole' and max(name) = 'Systole' then
      concat(
        min(case when name = 'Diastole' then results end),
        '/',
        min(case when name = 'Systole'  then results end)
      )
    else min(results) end AS results
from mytable t
where results is not null
group by
  service,
  ID,
  Date,
  state,
  case when name not in ('Systole', 'Diastole') then name end;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e70dc5f4370eb85ed137999df3b8dd93)